# Uncaught ReferenceError: 'a' is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (gallery.html:1)

Tags: javascript, firebase

When I create a new div element, I want the button to perform an onClick event that will capture the ${Title} variable. Then the getTitle(Title) function will take ${Title} as a parameter and use module.exports so that I can use this variable in another javascript file. (the way I use module.exports is through browserify.)

```
function createDiv(Title){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', `column-photo ${Type} show`);

    var newDiv =
        `
            <div class="content">
            <button class="content-text" id="Btn" onClick="getTitle(${Title})">
            </button>
            </div>
            `;

    div.innerHTML = newDiv;
    document.getElementById('someID').prepend(div);

}

function getTitle(Title){
    var imageTitle = Title.value;
    module.exports = imageTitle;
    console.log(imageTitle);
}
```

However, the problem here is that it throws an error when I click the button:
(${Title} = 'a' and filename is gallery.html)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: 'a' is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (gallery.html:1)
```

The other javascript file will import this variable. However, console.log(imageTitle.imageTitle) is undefined. How do I fix this?

```
var imageTitle = require('./file.js');
console.log(imageTitle.imageTitle);
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: sorry, I just changed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When constructing the HTML element, you need to properly inject the function parameter. The error lays in this line:

```
onClick="getTitle(${Title})"
```

if the `Title` is `"a"`, then after building the string, it becomes:

```
onClick="getTitle(a)"
```

which produces this error because `a` is not defined anywhere.

To fix this, change the line to this one:

```
onClick="getTitle('${Title}')"
```

which will be properly resolved to:

```
onClick="getTitle('a')"
```

Comment: Thanks! I did this but now it tells me this:

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at getTitle (VM26174 create.js:98)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Gallery.html:1)

Comment: Looks like your browserify config is not well defined. It should allow you to use `module`.

Comment: I'm confused. I fixed that but now it tells me this:

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: getTitle is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Gallery.html:1)